# Cocoa-Touch: UIWindow not rotating some subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iPad app that is set to start in landscape mode.

From what I read, the UIWindow itself doesn't need to be rotated, instead it will apply a rotation transform to all of it's subviews when the device is rotated.

My application has a `UINavigationController` which has the app's views, and above it a custom `MenuBarViewController` which will show sometimes on one edge of the screen.

In my app delegate's `didFinishLaunching..` I do:

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window addSubview:menuBarWrapperViewController.view];
[window bringSubviewToFront:menuBarWrapperViewController.view];
```

The views within my navigationController seem to be fine, however the view in my MenuBarViewController are not rotated.

I've checked, and both my `MenuBarViewController` and my `MenuBarWrapperViewController` (which doesn't do anything yet) return `YES` to `shouldAutorotate..`

Does anyone have any idea why one of my UIViews subviews doesn't get the correct rotation transform?

EDIT: upon further investigation, it seems that UIWindow only applies the transform to the *first* added subview, so if I change the order of `addSubview` calls, only the first subview will be rotated.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should try having one view controller be in charge of handling all rotations of all subviews being displayed.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, but I'd like to find out why and remove this hack.